# How can I compare each RDD line to other lines? Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working actually on an RDD containing the protein names and their domains.
Example : **'PO7K9I'** as protein name and **'IPR036291;IPR0023'** as domains
I would like actually to compute the **similarity** between protein domains, as example, similarity=1 two proteins have exactly same domains, similarity=  0.75 the two proteins share only 3 commun domains/4 and finally similarity=0 : no commun domain has been found between the 2 proteins.
can you please help me?

THis is how my rdd look like:

`(P25720,IPR002425;IPR036291;IPR020904;IPR0023) (Q9X2F4,IPR006047;IPR013780;IPR0178) (Q29228,IPR016161;IPR016163;IPR016160;IPR029510;IPR016162;IPR0155) (A5N376,IPR000821;IPR009006;IPR011079;IPR001608;IPR020622;IPR0290) (Q5HG16,IPR001792;IPR036046;IPR0179)`

Comment: Can you share sample output for the you input gave?

Comment: i didn't wrote any code the result that i shared above is the result of my rdd println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this way

```
val rdd = (P25720,IPR002425;IPR036291;IPR020904;IPR0023) (Q9X2F4,IPR006047;IPR013780;IPR0178) (Q29228,IPR016161;IPR016163;IPR016160;IPR029510;IPR016162;IPR0155) (A5N376,IPR000821;IPR009006;IPR011079;IPR001608;IPR020622;IPR0290) (Q5HG16,IPR001792;IPR036046;IPR0179)

val combs = rdd.cartesian(rdd) // for creating the Combinations
combs.map(your similarityCheck func)
```

Comment: oh the few lines that i shared above isn't the entire rdd, my rdd contains millions of lines extracted from a csv file. can you please tell how can i make combinations?

Comment: 'cartesian'  method of rdd helps you to do that

Comment: oh thank you i tried it and it works for me, still thinking abt how could i build my similaritycomputing function..

Comment: try converting the domain string to List/set then take a intersection across the two proteins on the domain List/Set, which will give you a common domains

Comment: do you mean i have to convert just one rdd column to list or both? entry and domains

Comment: as per the sample rdd 'P25720' protien( entry)  a single value so need not be converted to List; IPR002425;IPR036291;IPR020904;IPR0023 domains they can be split by ';' to convert to Array/List/Set